# malloc() in Linux - "there is no guarantee that the memory really is available"?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I'm making a game where the world is divided into chunks of data describing the world. I keep the chunks in a dynamically allocated array so I have to use `malloc()` when initializing the world's data structures.

Reading the [`malloc()` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html), there is a Note as follows:

> By default, Linux follows an optimistic memory allocation strategy.
>   This means that when `malloc()` returns non-NULL there is no guarantee
>   that the memory really is available.  In case it turns out that the
>   system is out of memory, one or more processes will be killed by the
>   OOM killer.  For more information, see the description of
>   */proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory* and */proc/sys/vm/oom_adj* in `proc(5)`, and the Linux kernel source file
>   *Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting*.

If Linux is set to use optimistic memory allocation then does this mean it doesn't always return the full amount of memory I requested in the call to `malloc()`?

I read that optimistic memory allocation an be disabled by modifying the kernel, but I don't want to do that.

So is there a way to check whether the program has allocated the requested amount?

Comment: Initialize every `malloc`-ed zone

Comment: That "checks" in the sense that the program (or some other process) may crash if the allocation failed.

Comment: The OOM killer can strike on a write to an *initialized* page if it’s CoW (*e.g.*, all your data pages after `fork`).

Answer (score 7):

This is not something you need to deal with from an application perspective. Users who don't want random processes killed by the "OOM killer" will disable overcommit themselves via

```
echo "2" > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

This is their choice, not yours.

But from another standpoint, it doesn't matter. Typical "recommended" amounts of swap are so ridiculous that no reasonable amount of `malloc` is going to fail to have physical storage to back it. However, you could easily allocate so much (even with forced `MAP_POPULATE` or manually touching it all) to keep the system thrashing swap for hours/days/weeks. There is no canonical way to ask the system to notify you and give an error if the amount of memory you want is going to bog down the system swapping.

The whole situation is a mess, but as an application developer, your role in the fix is just to use `malloc` correctly and check for a null return value. The rest of the responsibility is on distributions and the kernel maintainers.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Does every program need to document this? Is it necessary to document each known Linux bug/misfeature that might affect your program? I agree that if you've observed issues in practice it might be worth documenting something like: "This program needs X amount of memory. If you experience heavy swapping or crashes in this or other programs while running it, you need more physical ram. You might consider disabling overcommit (see xxxx documentation) so that the condition is diagnosed rather than triggering OOM killer." But otherwise I'd just leave it alone.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `malloc` you can allocate the necessary memory directly by `mmap`, with `MAP_POPULATE` that advises the kernel to map the pages immediately.

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

// allocate length bytes and prefault the memory so 
// that it surely is mapped
void *block = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
       MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_POPULATE,
       -1, 0);

// free the block allocated previously
// note, you need to know the size
munmap(block, length);
```

But the better alternative is that usually the world is saved to a file, so you would `mmap` the contents directly from a file:

```
int fd = open('world.bin', 'r+');
void *block = mmap(NULL, <filesize>, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

The file `world.bin` is mapped into the memory starting from address `block`; all  changes to the memory would also written transparently to the file - no need to worry if there is enough RAM as linux will take care of mapping the pages in and out automatically.

---

Do note that some of these flags are not defined unless you have a certain feature test macro defined:

> Certain  flags constants are defined only if either `_BSD_SOURCE` or
>   `_SVID_SOURCE` is defined.  (Requiring `_GNU_SOURCE` also suffices, and requiring that macro specifically would have been more logical, since
>   these flags are all Linux-specific.)  The relevant flags are:
>   `MAP_32BIT`, `MAP_ANONYMOUS`  (and  the  synonym  `MAP_ANON`), 
>   `MAP_DENYWRITE`,  `MAP_EXECUTABLE`, `MAP_FILE`, `MAP_GROWSDOWN`, `MAP_HUGETLB`,
>   `MAP_LOCKED`, `MAP_NONBLOCK`, `MAP_NORESERVE`, `MAP_POPULATE`, and `MAP_STACK`.

Comment: it is `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, and `MAP_POPULATE` requires kernel 2.6.23 for use with `MAP_PRIVATE`.

Comment: I have the Arch stock kernel version 3.18. Is there something i have to include or define? I already included sys/mman.h.

Comment: Yes, but your linux header files must be off. Ubuntu here, `MAP_POPULATE = 0x8000`, `MAP_PRIVATE = 0x20`, works and `#define`d within `#include <sys/mman.h>`.

Comment: I chaged my standard to gnu99 (not c99) and now the constants exist.