# How much memory a program can allocate?

Tags: c++, linux, out-of-memory

How much memory can I allocate for a C++ program running under Linux? In my test case, using `new` or `malloc` can allocate more than 170Gb of memory. 
 As a comparison, The same code can only allocate 1.8G in windows and then terminated.

My test machine, one is a virtual machine using virtual box, centos7 64-bit, 2Gb memory. The host is win10 64-bit, memory 8Gb.

Screenshot of using the free command,
[image]

Below is the test code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

 #define EVERY_ALLOC_MEM 1024 * 1014 // 1Mb
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << getpid() << ":" << argv[0] << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; ; i++)
    {
        //char* mem = new char[EVERY_ALLOC_MEM];
        char* mem = (char*)malloc(EVERY_ALLOC_MEM);
        std::cout << "used " << i  << "Mb, that is " << i * 1024 << "Kb, and " << (float)i/1024 << "Gb"<< std::endl;       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you're seeing is Linux's optimistic-memory-allocation behavior:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267364/malloc-in-linux-there-is-no-guarantee-that-the-memory-really-is-available

Comment: I test 'cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory', the result is zero, which means when user space requests more memory, the kernel evaluates the current amount of free memory, and if it is enough, can allocates, or fail.So still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed Linux's memory optimization technology. If you try to write to the allocated memory, such as `memset(mem, 0, EVERY_ALLOC_MEM)`, it will be revealed. This is related to **page fault**.